# Why is the Bode plot of 1/s a straight line?

Tags: bode-plot

The magnitude of the impedance of a capacitor is \$(\omega C)^{-1}\$. Plotting the impedance vs frequency should be a curve with slope \$-1/(\omega ^2C)\$. Why is it plotted as a straight line with a slope of -20dB/dec?

Thanks

Comment: The value in `dB` units is proportional to the `log` of the "plain" value. Try it out.

Comment: @EugeneSh. but the frequency axis is log as well so straight lines should stay straight and curves should stay curvy, no?

Comment: `log(1/x) = log(1)-log(x)`. But your `x` is is gaining power of 10 every "tick", so `log(x)` will have a constant step every tick.

Comment: No.  \$y=x^a\$, plotted on a log-log graph, is a straight line with slope \$a\$, and \$1/\omega = \omega^{-1}\$.  This is pretty basic stuff -- you may want to brush up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight line with a slope of -20dB/dec **IS** a curve with a slope of \$\frac{1}{\omega^2 C}\$.

Think about it.

> \$ 10*log_{10}(\frac{1}{\omega^2 C}) = \$
>  \$ -10*log_{10}(\omega^2 C) = \$
>
>
>  \$ -20*log_{10}(\omega) - 10*log_{10}(C)) \$

A Bode plot is in a linear dB scale in the ordinate and logarithmic scale in the abscissa.

Comment: Why would someone want to read your answer but not read the entire answer? I don't think you need to worry about spoiling the ending.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Well. It is teaching some of us the trick of hiding spoilers :)

Comment: \$\frac{1}{\omega^2 C}\$ is a slope of -40dB/decade. Gain in dB is \$\small -20 log (gain)\$, not  -\$\small 10 log (gain)\$. the slope of \$\frac{1}{\omega C}\$ is -20db/decade

Comment: @Chu note that the question is about *impedance* having such slope, not *voltage* gain. **Gain** in general refers to power gain, the Bell (or deciBell) scale refers to power, that's why we use a factor of 2 when we are talking about voltage (or current) gain. I have no idea of where the equations from the OP came from, but the only way to make sense of them is if you interpret them as I did.

Comment: \$\frac{1}{\omega C}\$ has a gain of  -20dB/decade, I've not seen power gain with reference to a capacitor.

Comment: @Chu \$ \frac{1}{\omega C} \$ does not *have* a gain, it is in fact an impedance. As such its units would be undefined if you are talking about dB. You can talk of it being a curve with a specific slope, but not as a *gain.*  I chose to ignore this inconsistency on the OP and interpret the equations in the only way they made sense, but do note that the OP never talks about a "gain."

Comment: @Chu What you seem to be missing is that it is irrelevant what you have seen or not seen. When you talk about dB you are **explicitly** talking about a power gain. Always.

Comment: So how does a power gain fit with a capacitor? A much more logical interpretation, of what is a badly constructed question, is to treat \$\frac{1}{sC}\$ as a transfer function where the input is current and the output is voltage. The gain of this is \$\frac{1}{\omega C}\$ and the magnitude frequency response is -20 dB/decade.

Answer (score 0):

Because we always plot the magnitude, an not the coplex impedance. If you take the magnitude of \$(j\omega C)^{-1}\$ you get \$(\omega C)^{-1}\$

[image]
Source: https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/emiconfun/capacitor/2013/02/14/en-20130214-p1